# How child classes communicate in Twin Design Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, subclass, multiple-inheritance

I was studying the Twin design pattern. I understood the concept, but when it came to implementation, I couldn't fully understand how the child classes communicate with each other.

How do the child classes communicate or exchange messages?

[Example image of twin design pattern structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOhBe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Two childs classes are able to communicate with each other as both compose objects of each other.

Let's take following example from [Wikipedia article "Twin pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_pattern#Sample_Code) to understand this:

```
public class BallItem extends GameItem {
     BallThread twin;

     int radius; int dx, dy;
     boolean suspended;

     public void draw(){
        board.getGraphics().drawOval(posX-radius, posY-radius,2*radius,2*radius);
     }

     public void move() { 
       posX += dx; posY += dy; 
     }

     public void click() {
       if (suspended) twin.resume(); else twin.suspend();
       suspended = ! suspended;
     }

     public boolean intersects (GameItem other) {
      if (other instanceof Wall)
       return posX - radius <= other.posX && other.posX <= posX + radius || posY - radius <= other.posY && other.posY <= posY + radius;

      else return false;
     }

     public void collideWith (GameItem other) {
      Wall wall = (Wall) other;
      if (wall.isVertical) dx = - dx; else dy = - dy;
     }
}
```

```
public class BallThread extends Thread {
   BallItem twin;
   public void run() {
     while (true) {
       twin.draw(); /*erase*/ twin.move(); twin.draw();
     } 
   }
}
```

Let's assume that BallThread wants to extend both Thread and BallItem. But if you see, BallThread has inherited Thread and has composed a BallItem class. By having a reference to BallItem class(or composing BallItem class), BallThread will be able to call all methods of BallItem class.

> Hence, BallThread is achieving Multiple Inheritance by inheriting Thread class and composing BallItem class.